# why .timeindex inf kafka store relative offset rather than the real position or relative position of log segment?

Tags: apache-kafka

It seems the title has described my problems.

Why `.timeindex` inf kafka store relative offset rather than the real position or relative position of log segment?

Answer (score 0):

*.timeindex* files are used for multiple purpose like cleaning segment files (with a configured time retention) or for responding to consumer offset requests.

Indeed, Kafka Consumers can retrieve logical offsets for specific partitions and unix timestamps. Brokers will then only used the timeindex to answer to clients. This will allow to reduce disk access to retrieve an offset.